# Equal Probability Problem

Tags: probability

One box contain $4$ red  balls and $5$ blue balls. Another box contains $6$ red balls and $7$ blue balls . For equal probability 
, if taken $2$ balls then what the probability of $1$ red ball and $1$ blue ball ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put some work into the problem.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you mean by "For equal probability, ...". Do you mean one of the boxes is chosen at random and two ball are taken from it?  Do you mean one of the boxes are chosen at random and one ball is taken from it, then another random choice of boxes is made and another ball taken?

Comment: Equal Probability means that equal chance to select any box  not more or less.

Comment: I takes 2 balls at a time then what the probability of  1 red ball and 1 blue ball ? I try following way :  Total red ball  4+6=10 , then probability of 1 red ball taken total red ball /total ball in two box  => 10/22 , by the same way probability of taken 1 blue ball is 12/22 and finally the

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few flaws in your logic.

Let $A = \{\text{Choose one red and one blue}\}$, and let $B_i =\{\text{Choose Box $i$}\}$ for $i = 1,2$.
Then notice that
$$P(A) = P(AB_1)+P(AB_2)$$
For $P(AB_i)$, if we apply the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_%28probability%29), 
then $$P(AB_i) = P(A|B_i)P(B_i),$$
where you tell us that $P(B_1) = P(B_2) = \frac{1}{2}$. I will assume that you draw without replacement (do not put the ball back). Then notice that either you draw a red then blue, or a blue then a red.
So, 
$$P(A|B_1) = P(RB|B_1)+P(BR|B_1) = \frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{5}{8}+\frac{5}{9}\cdot\frac{4}{8} = \frac{5}{9}.$$
Similarly
$$P(A|B_2) = P(RB|B_2)+P(BR|B_2) = \frac{7}{13}.$$
Finally, we have
\begin{align*}
P(A) &= P(AB_1)+P(AB_2)\\
&=P(A|B_1)P(B_1)+P(A|B_2)P(B_2)\\
&=\frac{5}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{7}{13}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\frac{64}{117}\\
&=0.5470085
\end{align*}